# Clone a direct array in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a path that contains an array with more than 10,000 items. I want to clone this route but without lowering the data directly from the database. Is it possible? Is There some function of the Firebase api that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has no built-in API to copy or move an entire node somewhere else in the JSON tree. You will have to download the items and re-insert them.